# how to replace the uncommon characters between two strings with 'x'?

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching

I have a dictionary of string counts: `{"abcd12efgh":1,"abcd23efgh":1,"abcd567efgh":1,"abcdkljefgh":1, "dog":1, "cat":1}`

I need to group together similar strings and aggregate the counts to get something like: `{"abcdxxxefgh":4,"dog":1,"cat":1}.`

Which is the most elegant way to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: This really depends on how your making the decision to classify the words as similar enough to group.  How you're doing that now does not make sense to me.  Would 'dog' == 'dig' == ' dug' in this grouping method?

Comment: I think you should worry about doing it any way before worrying about doing it an elegant way.

Comment: @Vikas, I would imagine that people are down voting this question because Stack Overflow is about asking more specific questions. This seems like a way of getting out of coding something for yourself.

Comment: your answer is in the docs https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#counter-objects

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you assumed two keys match, however you can have a separate function decide that. I have written one that might be what you are looking for: check if the key has certain prefix and suffix. You can add more constraints like, the sub string in between has certian lengths or another pattern.

```
def transform(key):
    prefix, suffix = 'abcd', 'efgh'
    transformed = key
    if key.startswith(prefix) and key.endswith(suffix):
        transformed = prefix + 'X' + suffix
    return transformed

new_d = {}
for k in d:
    new_d[transform(k)] = new_d.get(transform(k), 0) + d[k]

#{'abcdXefgh': 4, 'cat': 1, 'dog': 1}
```